# Correct way to type hint protected / private classes in Python?

Tags: python, annotations, lxml, type-hinting

I have a sample class here that I would like to use lxml to parse xml files.

```
class XMLParser:

    def __init__(self, path: str):
        self.root: etree._Element | None = None
```

However, PyCharm complains about access to a protected member _Element when I use this type hint. Is there a more correct way to annotate such a variable? The _Element class is the correct one when I type check this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Python doesn't have a formalized way to declare private / protected, but there is a common convention to use a single leading underscore (like ```_Element```) to indicate module-local or class-local symbols.  PyCharm is giving you a warning but your code is totally legal python; it's just considered "impolite" in certain circles

Comment: That makes sense. I guess as a follow-up, is there a "polite" way to type hint a protected class? Or is it preferred to just not use type hints in this case?

Comment: If you're using it in another class as you are here, it's not "protected", and you should just rename it to `Element` to formally make it part of the interface.  Python doesn't have any concept of "friend classes", even by convention -- if you feel it's appropriate to consider this class "protected" but need to make a specific exception, use a `# pylint: ignore` or whatever the appropriate linter override is for Pycharm.

Comment: **Python doesn't have protected or private classes**. Python *doesn't have access modifiers at all*

Comment: "PyCharm complains about access to a protected member" so just ignore PyCharm?

Comment: @Samwise I believe this is from the `lxml` library

Comment: Ah, so `etree.Element` is a factory which wraps the actual class which is `etree._Element`, which they never intended you to use directly because they weren't thinking about type annotations.  Yech!  Looks like you might need https://pypi.org/project/lxml-stubs/ to be able to annotate these things correctly?  I assume it's possible to make it all work in a nice way with `Protocol`s etc.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach for OP is to ignore `PyCharm` warnings. With my few years of experience [working on lxml type annotations](https://github.com/abelcheung/types-lxml), the "public" / "private"-ness and class names do not have definite relation -- some private structures unable to be constructed by users have public-class-like names (exported publicly and without underscore, like `DocInfo`).

Although `etree._Element` is seemingly declared as "private" by author, lxml users simply can't avoid it in function signatures. The same is also true for other "private" classes like `_ElementTree`, `_Comment` etc.