# Type hints for lxml.etree._Element

Tags: python, lxml, python-typing

I often work with the `lxml` and my IDE (PyCharm 2021.2.2) warns me about accessing a protected member of the module in my type hints because many of my function use `lxml.etree._Element` as inputs or outputs. But as many functions of `lxml.etree` returns `_Element` objects I think it must be normal to use them.

For example this code

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.parse(r"C:\xmlfile.xml").getroot()
print(type(root))
```

prints : `<class 'lxml.etree._Element'>`

What should I do to get rid of those warnings ? Should I configure my IDE to ignore them or is there a cleaner way to make the type hints ?

[image: IDE warning]

Comment: I'd disable this warning, because `lxml` was developed long ago without any annotations in perspective, and so `_Element` was just a private implementation detail. It was made private to avoid direct construction (`_Element` is intended to be created with `Element()` **function**, not via class `__init__`). Using private members for annotations in such case looks absolutely sane to me - you just have no alternatives, and even if something changes there in a backwards-incompatible way, the only thing that may break is you `mypy` call in CI pipeline - no one will die with unexpected exception.

Comment: For reference, here's the relevant [definition in stubs](https://github.com/lxml/lxml-stubs/blob/master/lxml-stubs/etree.pyi)

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/70310417/407651